# Mi dominio parked

Tags: wordpress, dominio, godaddy

Quiero registrar mi dominio en godaddy pero me dice que dominio no esta disponible y en wordpress me dice que el dominio esta parked. Anteriormente usaba wordpress.

Comment: Si no esta disponible entonces lo has perdido, a menos que haga menos de 2/3 meses, ante lo cual puedes mirar de recuperarlo pagando un buen dinero al mismo registrador que lo tenias. Si ya ha pasado mas tiempo entonces nada, ahora es de otro y tendrias que intentar comprarselo a el, pero seguro que tepide   mucho dinero.

Comment: Hacer un WHOIS y ver quién lo tiene para seguir la sugerencia de @masterguru. https://www.whois.com/